# Model structure when entities having some properties in common

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 entities in Core Data which have some common properties. I have to show both the entities in a same list view. What will be the best practice to do this? Can I do some inheritance thing and put common properties in base class?

Answer (score 0):

Core Data supports inheritance.
Open your core data model and select the child entity. Make sure the utilities pane is displayed (top right button in Xcode) and select "Show the data model inspector" (right most icon in the utilities pane).

Here you can select a parent entity for your entity. All attributes of the parent will be available in the child entity.

[image]

- [Apple documentation on Core Data inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html)

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the best practice to do this?

It depends on what type of entities you need to model. For example, if you have a `Cat` and a `Dog`, you should move the attributes in common in a base entity (say `Animal` or whatever you want). In other words, you should have a reason for doing this, i.e. entities have a sort of relationship each others.

> Can I do some inheritance thing and put common properties in base class?

Yes of course. In a model you are allowed to have a sort of inheritance pattern like the following.

[image]

where

[image]

I would stress two things here.

First, you can make base entity as an **Abstract Entity**. In this way, you are not allowed to create instances of this entity.

[image]

As per the doc.

> You can specify that an entity is abstract—that is, that you will not
>   create any instances of that entity. You typically make an entity
>   abstract if you have a number of entities that all represent
>   specializations of (inherit from) a common entity which should not
>   itself be instantiated. For example, in a drawing application you
>   might have a Graphic entity that defines attributes for x and y
>   coordinates, color, and drawing bounds. You never, though, instantiate
>   a Graphic. Concrete sub-entities of Graphic might be Circle, TextArea, and Line.

Second, under the hood Core Data will create a single table with all the attributes you have inserted. So, if you have a lot attributes, you will have a lot of columns for a table.

[image]